# How can I study PhD in business after masters in physics?

Tags: phd, changing-fields, business-school

I got master in Physics and now I am thinking to continue for PhD in marketing, business or Entrepreneurship and Innovation.

Is it possible to switch for Phd? How can I do that and how should I persuade admission committee?

Answer (score 2):

It is very possible to switch majors. If possible, try to talk with a faculty member with whom you are interested in working. If they are willing to work with you then the admissions process is likely to be fairly simple.

With that said, a PhD in business is meant to prepare you for teaching or a career in academia, not in actual business. If you want business skills for work outside of academia, an MBA is the way to go. Considering this, an admissions board / faculty member is probably most interested in your aptitude to publish. Your masters shows strong quantitative skills and so if you have any publications, that will likely go a long way in helping you get started.

All of these are very general statements, if you are really serious about a PhD then you should definitely contact schools you are interested in and see if you can talk with faculty.

Answer (score 1):

Switching fields this drastically takes some work. You probably will not be able to go directly, although many business schools are dying for more quantitative people, so that could change things. 
Really, though, you probably won't have a hard time convincing the admissions committee that you are smart enough to do a PhD. What you need to show them is that you are genuinely invested in the topic and have legitimate interest in it - that it's not just a passing "fad" for you, which you won't complete. Ways to do that include:

1. Get a second masters.
2. Find someone who does the kind of research you do, and work with them for a year or two.
3. Since you want to do marketing/business stuff, you really should think about working in this field in industry for a few years, first. Many business PhD programs won't even admit people who don't have "real world" experience.

Of these, the third is probably best. It will take time, but will also leave you in the best position to pursue your PhD of choice.